# How can i make the sound louder with Naudio c#?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, wave

I am trying to increase the amplitude of the sound wave in my code. I have the buffer consisting of all the bytes needed to make the wave.

Here is my code for the audio Playback:

```
public void AddSamples(byte[] buffer)
{
   //somehow adjust the buffer to make the sound louder 

    bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    WaveOut waveout = new WaveOut();
    waveout.Init(bufferedWaveProvider);
    waveout.Play();

    //to make the program more memory efficient
    bufferedWaveProvider.ClearBuffer();
 }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the examples? At least the AudioPlaybackDemo has a volume slider: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudioDemo/AudioPlaybackDemo/AudioPlaybackPanel.cs Worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert to an `ISampleProvider` and then try to amplify the signal by passing it through a `VolumeSampleProvider` with a gain > 1.0. However, you could end up with hard clipping if any samples go above 0.

```
WaveOut waveout = new WaveOut();
var volumeSampleProvider = new VolumeSampleProvider(bufferedWaveProvider.ToSampleProvider());
volumeSampleProvider.Volume = 2.0f; // double the amplitude of every sample - may go above 0dB
waveout.Init(volumeSampleProvider);
waveout.Play();
```

A better solution would be to use a dynamic range compressor effect, but NAudio does not come with one out of the box.

Comment: thanks that helped a lot. Sorry for not being able to add to your rep but i don't have 15 yet myself :(.

Comment: @pabolo12, you have that much rep now.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, too. But Could done with it with this link:

http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.hu/2009/10/playback-of-sine-wave-in-naudio.html

If you know all details about your sound It would be helpful I think