# I am using nAudio library to record from MIC, How to increase gain of MIC?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, audio-recording, naudio

```
WaveIn InputSource = new WaveIn() { DeviceNumber = deviceNumber, WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, WaveIn.GetCapabilities(cmbInputDevices.SelectedIndex).Channels) };  
InputSource.DataAvailable += (s,e)
{
    //Lines to write into a wave file
};
InputSource.RecordingStopped += (s,e)
{

};
```

This is the snippet I use to record from default input device which fine, but as my mic sensitivity is not good I want to increase gain so that I could get a louder recording

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i make the sound louder with Naudio c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067902/how-can-i-make-the-sound-louder-with-naudio-c)

Comment: Volume and Gain are two different things. I have seen a code sample to add gain to mic signals before hitting the "InputSource.DataAvailable" event but he was using cscore library. I can also use that library but I need to get mic level as well, which I could not able to get it

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample Voice recorder. It is a sample application demonstrating how to use NAudio to record audio
[Voice Recorder](https://github.com/markheath/voicerecorder)